# Clear value of cell when another cell contains a particular value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not very good at this, but have tried to make a script which looks at my spreadsheet, and if it sees a '1' in a particular column ('AW'), deletes the value from another column on the same row ('L').

I feel like I'm getting quite close with the below, but nothing is happening when I run the script. There are most likely lots of things wrong with this and I'm sorry if this is not the right way to ask my question - it told me previous questions I've asked have not been well received and I'm liable to get banned from asking any more. I've been looking myself for an answer for the last 48 hours.

```
function wipeName() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var r = s.getRange('AW2:AW51');
if( s.getName() == "GB Spreadsheet" ) 
{
       if( r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == '1') 
       {
          var nextCell = r.offset(0, -37);
              nextCell.clearContent();
       }
}
}
```

When it's run, I'd like the value in column 'L' to be removed, when there's a '1' in column 'AW'. It's not removing this value though, I don't get any error messages.

Comment: I would take the range of AW2:AW51  and L2;L51 and loop through the AW range and whenever I find that one there I’d set the value of L in that row to null and then after the end of the loop take that L range and Do setValues on that range

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what this means though, I know how to define the other range bit not sure what you mean by looping through...

Comment: Take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function wipeName(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg1=sh.getRange('AW2:AW51');//condition range
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=sh.getRange('L2:L51');//output range
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++){
    if(vA1[i][0]==1){//note: single columns are still 2d arrays. If condition range equals 1 the set output range to null
      vA2[i][0]='';
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vA2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
    function check() {
  var check = "C:C",
      target = "H:H",
      state = 2,
      s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      r = s.getRange(check),
      t = s.getRange(target),
      lr = s.getLastRow()-1, //last data without header
      rc = r.getColumn(),
      tc = t.getColumn(),
      r2 = s.getRange(state,rc,lr,1), //get specific range
      val = r2.activate().getValues();
  Logger.log(val.length); //Logger will give current data length

  for(var x = 0; x<val.length; x++){
    if(val[x][0]==1){
      var dat = s.getRange(x+state,tc).activate();
      dat.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

make sure you change var **check** and **target**
[check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMsEz.png)

Comment: Thanks both! I've not tried the second one you posted GB_Sources as Cooper's worked just fine. This is awesome and just what I need. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes ... agree, it is just a dumb thing to find out where my cursor is and track it will choose the right cell. hahaha, you can take it off